# React native json response failed to parse

Tags: react-native

I just get data from API using react native. The code is just like this.

```
fetch(Config.SERVER_URL + '/api/login/tokencheck/' + accessToken, {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
       'Accept': 'application/json',
       'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }
})
.then((response) => response.text())
.then((responseJson) => {

    alert(responseJson);

    alert(JSON.stringify(responseJson));


})
.catch((error) => {
    alert("error");         
    alert(error);
    console.log(error);
})
```

The problem is, at the first alert at callback, It show me a string that have json format like this `{"name": "Abigail","state": "CA"}`

But when I convert that response to json using `JSON.parse` It return error unexpected token '?' . But when I active react-native Remote Debuger, it work very well.

Answer (score 0):

Even I was facing this problem earlier. I think this should do it.

```
componentDidMount() {
            return fetch('http://example.com/getData')
                .then((response) => response.json())
                .then((responseJson) => {
                    this.setState({
                        isLoading: false,
                        data: responseJson,
                    }, function () {
                        // do something with new state
                    });
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.error(error);
                });
        }
```

I hope that helps :)

Comment: You can use your data like this. **this.state.data**